# How to make a fluid simulation start from the middle of an animation and make the domain not visible until that point?

Tags: physics, fluid-simulation

Using blender 2.9, I am trying to simulate water filling a vessel. I watched to some videos, like this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1YKDUPEZc1g&t=321s. Note that in this video, the animation has 100 frames, the flow beginning in the very first frame and lasting up to frame #51.

However, I am trying an animation with 200 frames with the flow beginning only at frame #75 and lasting up to frame #125.

The problem is when I set `Physics Properties - Cache - Frame start: 75` and `Physics Properties - Cache - End: 125`.

When I play the animation from frame #1, the vessel is blocked by the solid cube domain, which disappears when the flow starts.

My question is: How to make water start pouring in the middle of the animation?

Thank you!

** **EDIT: .blend file added.** **

[image]

Comment: show us your .blend file.

Comment: Hi @Chris. How do I add a file here?

Comment: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ read and follow instructions

Comment: Thank you very much @Chris. I just edited the question with the MWE .blend file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. in the domain, change the frames from 0 to 250 (or however your flow simulation lasts)
2. do not keyframe inflow type (delete those keyframes)
3. do keyframe use flow (74 - off, 75 - on)

[image]
4) free bake and bake all

-> works

visibility:

the domain itself normally is not visible, but the effector might be visible.

you can keyframe the visibility of objects here:

[image]

[image]